# Make Team City build result(couple of str variable) avaliable via HTTP API

Tags: api, http, teamcity

I have a build with Command line build step with app which have couple of str variables as a result. I can make this str avaliable via HTTP api after build finish.

I tried print to STDOUT '##teamcity[setParameter name='env.' value='']'  - this ENV variables available via `buildParameters` tab but missing in `https://<TC_HOST>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:<BUILD_ID>` resource. How to make  this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `https://<TC_HOST>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:<BUILD_ID>/resulting-properties`

Comment: God bless you, did't  found that in official documentation and start writing client which fetch hiden artefact, unzip propertie file )